# Why specifying Model in Backbone Collection

Tags: collections, model, backbone.js

What is the aim of specifying a model in a Backbone collection? It seems that the collection need its own url. Why do this:

```
Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url: '/rest/product',
  model: Model
});
```

Instead of:

```
Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url: '/rest/product'
});
```

With a model like this:

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
  url: function() {
    return '/rest/product/' + this.id;
  }
});
```

Is there a way to group `url` declaration?

Comment: You do realise `Model` is a factory right? To make a model you call `new Model`

Comment: @Raynos `Collection` is a factory; its `create` method uses POST as a factory. `Model` does not seems a factory to me, `new Model` does not create any representation server-side.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> What is the aim of specifying a model in a Backbone collection

```
Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url: '/rest/product',
  model: Model
});
```

Basically your saying every model inside the collection is an instance of `Model`. It's also useful for doing this

```
col.add({
  prop1: "foo", 
  ...
});
```

And it will call `new Model({prop1: "foo", ... })` for you and add it to the collection.

[`.model`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-models)

Comment: That does not say **why** — except for default attributes — specifying a `Model` to a `Collection`, it works perfectly without one.

Comment: @yvesamsellem yes it works without a model but then you don't have the extra sugar / shortcuts. You don't need one, it just makes life easier and it is self documenting.