# CakePHP with Backbone, fetch data only works in error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp, backbone.js

Ok, So I very new to Backbone, but I do like what I see. When I used it last time, it more or less worked for me without to many problems.

But now I have set up a CakePHP site with Backbone and when I call the view to load my collection, it will only display the data within the error callback?

So my setup, I have a route within my cake app, the points to my Pages Controller, with the fordwaring function:

```
public function PageDisplay($PageName = null) {

    switch($PageName) {
        case '':
            $this->render('index');
            break;
        case 'test':
            $this->layout = 'ajax';
            $this->autoRender = false;
            $this->render('test');
            break;  

    } 
} //end of function
```

This all works fine, the view file loads without any problems when loading the path.

Now this is my backbone setup:

```
var GetData = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: '/test'
});

var PageList = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $(".page"),

    render: function() {
        var that = this;
        var page = new GetData();

        page.fetch({        
            success: function(data) {
                //console.log(that);
                that.$el.html('content test here');
            },
            error: function(model, resp) {
                that.$el.html(resp.responseText );
                console.log(resp.responseText );
            }
        })
    } //End of render function

});
```

This works :( ? Where I places the responseText within my error callback, that will load the test page from my collection into the div tag on my index file (which my switch statement loads by default). So Why does my backbone code just load on the error? I have checked the network section within Chrome and there is a GET request with a 200 OK reply. Also when previewed the data is loaded.

So what am I doing wrong?

Please note, that I am not always very good at explaining myself in questions I post. Please just get me time and let me know if I am not clear in what I am asking. Or if I have there is more code or a section of code I have not posted, please just let me know and I will put it up.

Thanks,

Comment: I have been playing around with the code. But still do not have it working, I think, although Chromes network tab is telling me that the fetch call comes back as with 200, its CakePHP not sending the right information back once that request has been made, therefore giving backbone a error?

Comment: Try define model in your GetData  collection. Error in fetch method will be called only for not 200 responce. In Error callback call `console.log(response);` to check whole responce.

Comment: So is it best to always have a model? With your collections? I thought that collections where models but with an extension. Thanks,

Comment: extension to collection is different topic. Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265411/why-specifying-model-in-backbone-collection). Is specifying model help to avoyd error?

Comment: I added in a Model but no difference, it will still only display the data from my server on the error callback